# Sublime Text 2 Permission Denied

Tags: permissions, sublime-text

I use a Papyrus package with Sublime Text 2, but when I try to compile a file by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> or <kbd>F7</kbd> I get a permission error;

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied
[cmd:  [u'/home/sde/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/The Elder Scrolls V Skyrim/Papyrus Compiler/ScriptCompile.bat', u'/home/sde/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/The Elder Scrolls V Skyrim/Data/Scripts/Source/MyFirstScript.psc']]
[dir:  /home/sde/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/The Elder Scrolls V Skyrim/Data/Scripts/Source]
[path: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin]
[Finished]
```

Even when I run Sublime Text 2 as root. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using sublime text 2 windows version through wine?

Comment: No, unix version. Only alters/adds files in wineprefix.

Comment: I remember to never run wine applications with sudo.

Comment: Ah... perhaps Sublime Text 2 doesn't have permission because it uses Papyrus Compiler which is a wine application in this case? So in order to fix this, I have to run Sublime Text 2 Windows version in wine. Or Papyrus Compiler unix version.

Comment: I am unable to test, Sublime Text 2 (Windows version) crashes when started with wine. Unhandled exception, but can't get the report for some reason.

Comment: I don't think the problem has anything to do with Sublime Text, rather Papyrus compiler crashes (or the plugin you're installed is badly coded and is not cross-platform). Can you run the compiler in terminal to see if it works? If Unix version exists why are you not using it?

Comment: sde@sde:~/Skyrim/Papyrus Compiler$ sh ./ScriptCompile.bat
./ScriptCompile.bat: 1: ./ScriptCompile.bat: C:\Program Files\The Elder Scrolls V Skyrim\Papyrus Compiler\PapyrusCompiler.exe: not found
: not foundpile.bat: 2: ./ScriptCompile.bat: pause
sde@sde:~/Skyrim/Papyrus Compiler$ wine ScriptCompile.bat
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
fixme:process:SetProcessDEPPolicy (1): stub
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
wine: Bad EXE format for Z:\home\sde\Skyrim\Papyrus Compiler\ScriptCompile.bat.

Comment: PapyrusCompiler.exe does exist in that folder

Comment: /Skyrim/ is a link by the way.

Comment: Redownloaded Creation Kit Papyrus Compiler and the .exe seems to give better information now.

Comment: sde@sde:~/Skyrim/Papyrus Compiler$ wine Papyruscompiler.exe
fixme:module:GetModuleHandleExW should pin refcount for 0x79000000
fixme:thread:SetThreadStackGuarantee (0x32fc6c): stub
You must specify an object or folder name.
Usage:
PapyrusCompiler <object or folder> [<arguments>]
<br/> And a lot of options below here

Comment: Permission problem persists.

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.